# Getting Labels in a Tensorflow Image Classification

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, multiclass-classification, image-classification

I am doing image classification by following [this TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) and loading my own dataset from Gdrive.
Now I want to plot the confusion matrix. First, I predicted labels for the validation dataset:

```
val_preds = model.predict(val_ds)
```

but I am not sure how to get original labels to compare the prediction to them. I have tried different methods but I got very low accuracy so I know labels are not what they should be.

```
val_ds_labels = np.concatenate([y for x, y in val_ds], axis=0)
```

This gives me an accuracy of 0.067 while the below gives me an accuracy of around .70.

```
epochs = 10
history=model.fit(train_ds, epochs=epochs, validation_data=val_ds)
```

Here is how I created the validation and training dataset:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "images",
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    label_mode='int'
)
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "images",
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=123,
    image_size=image_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    label_mode='int'
)
train_ds = train_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=32)
val_ds = val_ds.prefetch(buffer_size=32)
```

Then created the model and compile it:

```
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseTopKCategoricalAccuracy(k=1)],
)
```

and fit

```
epochs = 10
history=model.fit(train_ds, epochs=epochs, validation_data=val_ds)
```

I have 22 labels.

```
val_preds = model.predict(val_ds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After training, get the true labels of the validation set as follows:

```
epochs=5
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)

....
....
Epoch 4/5
20ms/step - loss: 0.6368 - accuracy: 0.7613 - val_loss: 0.9294 - val_accuracy: 0.6185
Epoch 5/5
20ms/step - loss: 0.4307 - accuracy: 0.8531 - val_loss: 0.9552 - val_accuracy: 0.6635

# get the labels 
predictions = np.array([])
labels =  np.array([])

for x, y in val_ds:
  predictions = np.concatenate([predictions, np.argmax(model.predict(x), axis=-1)])
  labels = np.concatenate([labels, y.numpy()])

predictions[:10]
array([0., 4., 3., 0., 3., 4., 2., 4., 4., 0.])

labels[:10]
array([0., 4., 3., 0., 3., 4., 1., 2., 4., 0.])

m = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()
m(labels, predictions).numpy()
# 0.66348773
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I got this error while running this part
  predictions = np.concatenate([val_preds, np.argmax(model.predict(x), axis=-1)])
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)

Comment: I followed the same tf colab example, and use above code to get what you've asked. It should work for u too. Could u please share a colab with that error?

Comment: Upvoted. Maybe you want to change `model.predict(x)` with `model(x)` which is faster.

Comment: np.argmax(model(x), axis=-1) is giving an array but val_preds is giving array and, dtype=int32
Probably that is the problem.

Comment: I used labels from labels = np.concatenate([labels, y.numpy()])  from the loop you shared and just used y_pred = np.argmax(val_preds, axis=-1) out of the for loop. Still they don't match at all.

Comment: They should be in the same loop. @Hanna

Comment: The error is solved now! But again the accuracy is very low: 0.40625. The accuracy given by history is above.7
Can anyone help me with this?
predictions[:10]
array([ 1, 16, 18, 19, 12, 12,  2,  4, 11, 15])
labels[:10]
array([11.,  1., 19., 12.,  7.,  7.,  6.,  9., 13.,  9.])

Comment: @Hanna sorry for the late reply, fell asleep. If you have any queries further, please feel free to ask.

Comment: @M.Innat everything is solved now, thank you!

Comment: The accuracy I get after this method does not match what the history reports as the val_binary_accuracy: 0.6017.

I get: predictions = np.array([]) labels = np.array([])

for x, y in val_ds: predictions = np.concatenate([predictions, np.argmax(model.predict(x), axis=-1)]) labels = np.concatenate([labels, y.numpy()])

m = tf.keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy() m(labels, predictions).numpy()

0.44067797

any reason why this might be? My val_ds is a batch dataset, if this helps. Thank you!

Comment: I would look at if I shuffle the validation data in training time. Also, if drop_reminder is set True. If this isn't the case, please create new post, with reproducible example.